# use of icomparable in AVL Tree

Tags: c#, data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

```
 public class Node : IComparable

{
    public object element;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;
    public int height;


    public Node(object data, Node L, Node R)
    {

        element = data;
        left = L;
        right = R;
        height = 0;


    }
    public Node(object data)
    {

        element = data;
        left = null;
        right = null;
        height = 0;


    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return (this.element.CompareTo((Node)obj.element));


    }


}
```

in this avl tree i want to compare left and right node and other balance methode for it but in start point it doesn't support in compareto in this line of code

```
 public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return (this.element.CompareTo((Node)obj.element));


    }
```

although i used interface Icomaparable..anyone tell what is missing in it it??????????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `element` property is of type object, so it doesn't implement `IComparable`. Instead you could make a generic class with the constraint that the data element of type `T` must implement `IComparable<T>`:

```
public class Node<T> : IComparable<Node<T>> where T: IComparable<T>
{
    public T element;
    public Node<T> left;
    public Node<T> right;
    public int height;


    public Node(T data, Node<T> L, Node<T> R)
    {

        element = data;
        left = L;
        right = R;
        height = 0;


    }
    public Node(T data)
    {

        element = data;
        left = null;
        right = null;
        height = 0;


    }

    public int CompareTo(Node<T> other)
    {
        return element.CompareTo(other.element);
    }
}
```